# Swift cannot invoke '==' with an argument of type '(Int @lvalue [Int])'

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm really new to programing (so this may be a really dumb question) but I've tried to follow an udemy.com tutorial about building an iOSapp. But even though I've followed it step by step it wont let me compile. Would be very grateful if someone would take the time to help me =)

```
    func getSixRandom () -> String {
    var lottoBalls = [Int]()
    var result = ""
    var n = [Int(arc4random() % 49) + 1]

    lottoBalls += n

    while lottoBalls.count < 6 {
        n = [Int(arc4random() & 49) + 1]
        var found = false

    for ball in lottoBalls {
    // Throws an error!!

            if ball == n {
                found = true
            }
        }

        if found == false {
            lottoBalls += n
        }

    }

    result = "\(lottoBalls[0]), \(lottoBalls[1]), \(lottoBalls[2]), \(lottoBalls[3]), \(lottoBalls[4]), \(lottoBalls[5]) "

    return result
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what you should expect when comparing an Int to an [Int].

You need to change the following line:

```
var n = [Int(arc4random() & 49) + 1]
```

to:

```
var n = Int(arc4random() & 49) + 1
```

and do the same thing in any other location where you are setting `n`.